# PyTorch SSD (VGG16 backbone) is not learning

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection, torchvision

I am currently using PyTorch to try to train an SSD detector on a custom dataset. I previously completed training another model within the same framework, Faster RCNN, and was satisfied with the results (~80 mAP @IoU=0.50). However, training SSD does not seem to work at all.

This is what the metrics look like after training on a custom dataset for 25 epochs (around 5000 images in the dataset) with mini batch size of 32 and learning rate of 1e-3.

```
IoU metric: bbox
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.002
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.015
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.75      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.001
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.011
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=  1 ] = 0.011
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets= 10 ] = 0.018
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.062
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.174
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.100
```

Here is how I am trying to construct the model (all default to make bare minimum work first).

```
model = torchvision.models.detection.ssd300_vgg16(weights_backbone=torchvision.models.VGG16_Weights)
in_channels = det_utils.retrieve_out_channels(model.backbone, (300, 300))
num_anchors = model.anchor_generator.num_anchors_per_location()
model.head = SSDHead(in_channels=in_channels, num_anchors=num_anchors, num_classes=3)
```

I'm trying to load a pre-trained backbone for VGG (Imagenet), and then replacing the head which I believe should result in a model which has pre-trained weights for the feature extractor and xavier initialized weights for the head. Is this how it is supposed to be constructed?

Now I'm confident that the images are loaded correctly, as I use exactly the same `__getitem__()` function which I used to load the same data for Faster RCNN (+ this I confirmed with SSD code as well by visualizing the bounding boxes). The most common object in the dataset is not particularly small either, rather big (10-40% of image size).

I struggled to find any working examples with SSD, only Faster RCNN and some others. So what I'm doing is based on my understanding of SSD and inspecting the code in the repository, and that's why I believe I might be doing something wrong here in the model initialization.

EDIT:

Here's the optimizer

```
torch.optim.SGD(params, lr=0.001, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0005)
```

- PyTorch version: 1.13.0a0+git3c2c2cc
- Torchvision version: 0.14.0a0+6ca9c76
- GPU: RTX 3070
- CUDA version: 11.2
- CuDNN version: 8.2.1

PyTorch and Torchvision compiled from source

Comment: Have you normalized before feeding them to the model? The input of VGG should be normalized using values from IMageNet ([more details](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/models/generated/torchvision.models.vgg16.html)). Can you  also give information on the optimizer/learning rate

Comment: @theophile Added some extra information. The data is normalized utilizing the ImageNet values (those are the default values in the module).